# Gravityforms not found message - WP Plugin hook

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm trying to hook onto the WP Gravityforms plugin's not found message.
I've found a hook(gform_form_not_found_message) for this but it doesn't seem to be firing. What am I doing wrong here?
My code:

```
function notfoundmessage($message, $id){
    $message = 'test';
    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'gform_form_not_found_message', 'notfoundmessage', 10, 2);
```

I tried several thing like writing the function inline, including it from the main plugin file, including it in an oop way but none of them seem to work. I was thinking that maybe I need to require a gravityforms Class but I can't find anything about that in the documentation.

[Link to the hook in the documentation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_form_not_found_message/)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the filter isn't applied yet in the version I'm using. For other people having this issue, make sure you are using the latest version of Gravityforms.